# Confusion over CoreMIDI Destinations

Tags: swift, macos, coremidi

Given the following code if I use the first method in the `if` branch to obtain a `MIDIDestination` the code works correctly, and MIDI data is sent.  If I use the second method from the `else` branch, no data is sent.

```
var client = MIDIClientRef()
var port = MIDIPortRef()
var dest = MIDIEndpointRef()

MIDIClientCreate("jveditor" as CFString, nil, nil, &client)
MIDIOutputPortCreate(client, "output" as CFString, &port)

if false {
    dest = MIDIGetDestination(1)
} else {
    var device = MIDIGetExternalDevice(0)
    var entity = MIDIDeviceGetEntity(device, 0)
    dest = MIDIEntityGetDestination(entity, 0)
}

var name: Unmanaged<CFString>?
MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(dest, kMIDIPropertyDisplayName, &name)
print(name?.takeUnretainedValue() as! String)

var gmOn : [UInt8] = [ 0xf0, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x09, 0x01, 0xf7 ]

var pktlist = MIDIPacketList()
var current = MIDIPacketListInit(&pktlist)
current = MIDIPacketListAdd(&pktlist, MemoryLayout<MIDIPacketList>.stride, current, 0, gmOn.count, &gmOn)

MIDISend(port, dest, &pktlist)
```

In both cases the printed device name is correct, and the status of every call is `noErr`.

I have noticed that if I ask for the `kMIDIManufacturerName` property that I get different results - specifically using the first method I get `Generic`, from the USB MIDI interface to which the MIDI device is connected, and with the second method I get the value of `Roland` configured via the Audio MIDI Setup app.

The reason I want to use the second method is specifically so that I can filter out devices that don't have the desired manufacturer name, but as above I can't then get working output.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two methods, and why the latter doesn't work, and ideally offer a suggestion as to how I can work around that?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct `entity`? What about `MIDIDeviceGetNumberOfEntities`?

Comment: @Sulthan yes. there's only one `entity`, and per above, the displayed name is identical (and correct) either way.  However the returned unique IDs are not the same.

Comment: ok, interesting - if I use `MIDIGetDevice(4)` instead of `MIDIGetExternalDevice(1)` the code actually works and I get the same unique ID either way, except that I still get the wrong manufacturer ID (i.e. I get the one for the actual interface, not for the unit connected to it).  The docs aren't clear about the different between an "external" device and a normal device, here :(

Comment: I would try to print all destinations in all entities and in all devices... There is probably one that will match `MIDIGetDestination(1)`.

Comment: @Sulthan I have been trying to do something like that, but without success.  It seems like you can't get back the same `MIDIEndpointRef` if you enumerate the entities of all devices as you get when you ask specifically for a particular MIDI Destination.    Doing the latter gets me the connected synth's details, whereas going the other way gets me the _interface's_ details (except for the display name, which matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a hint from Kurt Revis's answer, I've found the solution.

The destination that I needed to find is associated with the *source* of the external device, with the connection between them found using the `kMIDIPropertyConnectionUniqueID` property of that source.

Replacing the code in the `if / else` branch in the question with the code below works:

```
var external = MIDIGetExternalDevice(0)
var entity = MIDIDeviceGetEntity(external, 0)
var src = MIDIEntityGetSource(entity, 0)

var connID : Int32 = 0
var dest = MIDIObjectRef()
var type = MIDIObjectType.other

MIDIObjectGetIntegerProperty(src, kMIDIPropertyConnectionUniqueID, &connID)
MIDIObjectFindByUniqueID(connID, &dest, &type)
```

A property dump suggests that the connection Unique ID property is really a data property (perhaps containing multiple IDs) but the resulting `CFData` appears to be in big-endian format so reading it as an integer property instead seems to work fine.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!  The value of that property may be *either* a single integer (in which case your code works) or a `CFData` containing multiple unique IDs. `MIDIObjectGetIntegerProperty` should return a nonzero error in the latter case.

Comment: @KurtRevis it appears possible to read a `CFData` that only contains a single integer as a single integer without any problems - I suspect that the deserialisation code doesn't care, but I should probably try to figure out programatically which one I'm getting.  The docs do say _"Beginning with CoreMIDI 1.3, this property may also be a CFDataRef containing an array of big-endian SInt32's, to allow specifying that a driver object connects to multiple external objects (via MIDI thru-ing or splitting)_"

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to find only the MIDI destination endpoints to talk to a certain manufacturer's devices. Unfortunately that isn't really possible, since there is no protocol for discovering what MIDI devices exist, what their attributes are, and how they are connected to the computer.

(Remember that MIDI is primitive 1980s technology. It doesn't even require *bidirectional communication*. There are perfectly valid MIDI setups with MIDI devices that you can send data to, but can never receive data from, and vice versa.)

The computer knows what MIDI interfaces are connected to it (for instance, a USB-MIDI interface). CoreMIDI calls these "Devices". You can find out how many there are, how many ports each has, etc. But there is no way to find out anything about the physical MIDI devices like keyboards and synthesizers that are connected to them.

"External devices" are an attempt to get around the discovery problem. They are the things that appear in Audio MIDI Setup when you press the "Add Device" button. That's all!

Ideally your users would create an external device for each physical MIDI device in their setup, enter all the attributes of each one, and set up all the connections in a way that perfectly mirrors their physical MIDI cables.

Unfortunately, in reality:

- There may not be any external devices. There is not much benefit to creating them in Audio MIDI Setup, and it's a lot of boring data entry, so most people don't bother.
- If there are external devices, you can't trust any of the information that the users added. The manufacturer might not be right, or might be spelled wrong, for instance.
- It's pretty unfriendly to force your users to set things up in Audio MIDI Setup before they can use your software. Therefore, no apps do that... and therefore nobody sets anything up in Audio MIDI Setup. It's a chicken-and-egg problem.
- Even if there are external devices, your users might want to send MIDI to other endpoints (like virtual endpoints created by other apps) that are not apparently connected to external devices. You should let them do what they want.

The [documentation for MIDIGetDevice()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1495368-midigetdevice) makes a good suggestion:

> If a client iterates through the devices and entities in the system, it will not ever visit any virtual sources and destinations created by other clients. Also, a device iteration will return devices which are "offline" (were present in the past but are not currently present), while iterations through the system's sources and destinations will not include the endpoints of offline devices.
>
> Thus clients should usually use MIDIGetNumberOfSources, MIDIGetSource, MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations and MIDIGetDestination, rather iterating through devices and entities to locate endpoints.

In other words: use `MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations` and `MIDIGetDestination` to get the possible destinations, then let your users pick one of them. That's all.

If you *really* want to do more:

- Given a destination endpoint, you can use `MIDIEndpointGetEntity` and `MIDIEndpointGetDevice` to get to the MIDI interface.
- Given any MIDI object, you can find its connections to other objects. Use [`MIDIObjectGetDataProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1495213-midiobjectgetdataproperty) to get the value of property [`kMIDIPropertyConnectionUniqueID`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/kmidipropertyconnectionuniqueid), which is an array of the unique IDs of connected objects. Then use [`MIDIObjectFindByUniqueID`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1495191-midiobjectfindbyuniqueid) to get to the object. The `outObjectType` will tell you what kind of object it is.

But that's pretty awkward, and you're not guaranteed to find any useful information.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but this is for a MIDI patch editor where virtual devices aren't required.  I had hoped to use the info configured via the Audio MIDI Setup app to not only get the manufacturer but also the SysEx device ID.   BTW, it seems that the connection unique IDs retrieved via the property are in big-endian format?  If I directly ask for the property as an Integer they seem correct, though.

Comment: I've dumped a tree of all destinations, devices and external devices on my system.  There's no apparent overlap between the unique connection IDs seen in Destinations and those for any external device. http://pastebin.com/93xhZCCJ

Comment: Yes, the unique IDs are supposed to be big-endian. It's unfortunately a pain to extract them from the `NSData`. I haven't ever done this in Swift, so maybe something is going wrong with the bridging? [Here's how I do it in Objective-C](https://github.com/krevis/MIDIApps/blob/master/Frameworks/SnoizeMIDI/SMEndpoint.m#L306) if that helps.

Comment: Also, I would be astonished if more than 1% of your users have set the SysEx Device ID in Audio MIDI Setup.

Comment: I'll _probably_ be the only user of this code, and I do have it set, so for now it's 100% :p

Comment: Ha - I didn't realise those apps were yours - I was just playing with them yesterday - cool! :)